# Sitecore presentation details showing error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

When I am clicking on the presentation details of content part, it is opening the dialog box where all existing placeholders are displayed. Now on a click of any item in the popup I get an error:

```
Value cannot be null, Parameter name: Key Details:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

Comment: Is this just for 1 item or for all? If for 1, could it be that your presentation details are just completely messed up? Maybe share a screenshot of the presentation details as a start..

Comment: Try to remove component one by one in Presentation Detail. Or, try to reset the item's presentation detail if you assume that its __Standard Values of data template doesn't have any error.

Comment: It is for all the items inside the popup

Comment: It is something which we get if the value of placeholder field is empty for components. I also faced same issue and after putting placeholder key in field it works for me

Answer (score 0):

@Nidhi Go to Presentation tab and click reset button on the menu. I think in one of the rendering it might have added either broken link or you might have forgot to add placeholder to one of the renderings.

Comment: Go to Navigate menu and click on links and you should be able to see broken links.